# CSS ul > li selector selecting nested lists

Tags: css, list

I've been reading about this everywhere, and from what I've read to select a list without selecting the nested list. I need to have this

```
.myclass > ul > li

//or  even just 

ul > li
```

I've been trying to get it to work unsuccessfully. The selector is selecting everything, including the nested list. What am I missing?

Please see the code on JS Bin:

http://jsbin.com/asipap/4/edit

Comment: You need to set a default style on the list that your specific rule will override.

Comment: nested li is inheriting the color. specify different color for them...

Comment: the selector is correct, you just dont have a default li color specified so the nested li is inheriting from the parent li anyway even though it isn't specifically selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some CSS styles are inherited from parent elements unless another style explicitly overrides it, you've set the `color` for all the list items, but haven't overridden it for any other matched selector. Simply adding `li { color: black }` should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks zzzzBov. You're right, AI had no default style for LI. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the ul that are inside an ul?

```
.cats, .cats ul{list-style-type:none;}
.test li ul > li{color:red;} /* li ul: an ul inside a li */
```

This select all nested list, maybe you want to use `>` to limit the deep.
See it here http://jsbin.com/asipap/16/

Answer (score 0):

This `li` element matches the `.test > ul > li` selector. Therefore, all text inside that `li` will be red, including the `ul` inside the `li`.

```
   <li>Test 1.1
     <ul>
       <li>nested</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
```